# How can I execute a python script dependent on extracting file name in another python gui script?

Tags: python, tkinter, operating-system

I created a python script (`NoShowCalc.py`) that automates data cleaning and analysis with 3 selected excel files (`booked_file_path`, `arrived_file_path`, and `vlookup_file_path`). However, I want this all to be executed through a GUI, so I started a separate (`GUI.py`) script to create an interface with browse buttons that will get those file path names, then that will get me what I need to execute the `NoShowCalc.py` script. Once those excel files are selected, another button is there to execute the `NoShowCalc.py` script. However, I did it and it worked! But I have no idea what I changed and now the two different py files are not connecting.

Here's the script in the `NoShowGUI.py` script:

```
def open_file():
browse_text.set('Loading...')
booked_file_path = askopenfile(parent=root, mode='rb', title='Choose a file', filetype=[('CSV file', '*.csv')])
if booked_file_path:
    read_csv = (booked_file_path)
    browse_text.set('Loaded')
```

```
def run():
    os.system('NoShow_Calc.py')
    calculate_text.set("Calculating...")
#Calculate button
calculate_text = tk.StringVar()
calculate_btn = tk.Button(root, textvariable=calculate_text, command=lambda:run(), font='Calibri', fg='black', height=1, width=15)
calculate_text.set("Calculate No Show")
calculate_btn.grid(column=2, row=9)
```

These are the first lines in the `NoShowCalc.py` script:

```
import pandas as pd 

booked = pd.read_csv(booked_file_path, parse_dates=['Appointment Date'])
arrived = pd.read_csv(arrived_file_path, parse_dates=['Appointment Date'])
vlookup = pd.read_excel(vlookup_file_path)
```

The error that keeps popping up is `NameError: name 'booked_file_path' is not defined`. I don't get how it ran before and now this error is popping up as it can't speak to the other py file anymore. What did I do wrong?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: if you use `os.system()` to run code then you can't use variable from other script. You can do it only if using `import` to load one script to another - like you do with module `pandas`

Comment: using `os.system()` you can only send value as argument `os.system('NoShow_Calc.py selecte_filename')` and get this value in `NoShow_Calc.py` using `sys.argv`  like `booked_file_path = sys.argv[1]`.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know if I'm following what you're saying.

Comment: I say that if you run it as `os.system()` then inside `NoShowCalc.py` you can't use variable `booked_file_path` from file `NoShowGUI.py` because it runs scripts as separated processes in system and separated processes doesn't share variables.

Comment: Ok, so how can I get `NoShowCalc.py` to read my variables in `NoShowGUI.py`?

Comment: you can only send text values as argument `os.system("NoShowCalc.py filename")` and get it  in `NoShowCalc` using `booked_file_path = sys.argv[1]`

Answer (score 0):

If you run script using `os.system()` or using module `subprocess` then you can't use variables from other script. They runs as separated processes and they can't share variable (or data in memory)

You can only send some text values as arguments

```
 os.system('NoShow_Calc.py ' + booked_file_path)
```

and then you can get it inside `NoShow_Calc` using `sys.argv`

```
import pandas as pd 
import sys

booked_file_path  = sys.argv[1]

booked = pd.read_csv(booked_file_path, parse_dates=['Appointment Date'])
arrived = pd.read_csv(arrived_file_path, parse_dates=['Appointment Date'])
vlookup = pd.read_excel(vlookup_file_path)
```

If you need other variables then you have to send other values in the same way

```
 os.system('NoShow_Calc.py ' + booked_file_path + ' ' + other_filename)
```

and

```
booked_file_path = sys.argv[1]
other_filename = sys.argv[2] 
# etc.
```

But using `os.system()` you can't send result `booked, arrived, vlookup` from `NoShow_Calc` to `NoShowGUI`.

You could do it with `subprocess` but it can send it only as text - so `NoShow_Calc` would have to use `print()` to display all result and `NoShowGUI` would have to parse this text to expected structure - ie. list, dictionary, `DataFrame`

---

Better you should use `import` to load code from `NoShow_Calc.py` and then all code runs in the same process so all code has access to the same variables - and it doesn't need to convert to text and back from text.

To make it better I put code in function

```
import pandas as pd 

def my_function(booked_file_path, arrived_file_path, vlookup_file_path):
    booked = pd.read_csv(booked_file_path, parse_dates=['Appointment Date'])
    arrived = pd.read_csv(arrived_file_path, parse_dates=['Appointment Date'])
    vlookup = pd.read_excel(vlookup_file_path)

    return booked, arrived, vlookup
```

and then in `NoShowGUI` you can import it and use like any other function

```
from NoShow_Calc import my_function

booked, arrived, vlookup = my_function(booked_file_path, arrived_file_path, vlookup_file_path)
```

---

**EDIT:**

I made minimal working code. I reduced it to only one filename.

**NoShow_Calc.py**

```
import pandas as pd 

def calc(booked_file_path): #, arrived_file_path, vlookup_file_path):
    booked = pd.read_csv(booked_file_path, parse_dates=['Appointment Date'])
    #arrived = pd.read_csv(arrived_file_path, parse_dates=['Appointment Date'])
    #vlookup = pd.read_excel(vlookup_file_path)
    
    return booked #, arrived, vlookup
```

**NoShowGUI.py**

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename   # instead of `askopenfile`

# adding directory with this script to `sys.path` before `import NoShow_Calc`
# to make sure that `import` will search `NoShow_Calc.py` in correct folder even when GUI will be run from different folder

import os
import sys

HOME_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
sys.path.append(HOME_DIR)

import NoShow_Calc

print('HOME_DIR:', HOME_DIR)

def select_filename():
    global booked_file_path  # inform function that it has to assign value to external/global variable 

    text_log.insert('end', 'Selecting ...\n')
    
    # use `askopenfilename` instead of `askopenfile` 
    # because I need only filename, not opened file (pandas will open it on its own)
    
    booked_file_path = askopenfilename(parent=root,                                        
                                       title='Choose a file', 
                                       #initialdir='/home/furas',
                                       filetypes=[('CSV file', '*.csv')])
    
    if booked_file_path:
        text_log.insert('end', f'Selected: {booked_file_path}\n')
    else:
        text_log.insert('end', f'Not selected\n')

def run():
    text_log.insert('end', "Calculating...\n")

    if booked_file_path is None:
        text_log.insert('end', "File booked_file_path not selected !!!")
        return
    #elif arrived_file_path is None:
    #    text_log.insert('end', "File arrived_file_path not selected !!!")
    #    return
    #elif vlookup_file_path is None:
    #    text_log.insert('end', "File vlookup_file_path not selected !!!")
    #    return
    else:        
        root.update()  # force tkinter to update text in text_log at once (not when it exits function `run`)
        result = NoShow_Calc.calc(booked_file_path)# , arrived_file_path, vlookup_file_path)

    text_log.insert('end', "Result:\n")
    text_log.insert('end', str(result.head()) + "\n")
    
# --- main ---    

booked_file_path = None  # default value at start (so in `run` I can check `None` to see if I selecte filename)
#arrived_file_path = None
#vlookup_file_path = None

root = tk.Tk()

text_log = tk.Text(root)
text_log.grid(column=0, row=0)

select_btn = tk.Button(root, text="Select File Name", command=select_filename)
select_btn.grid(column=0, row=1)

calculate_btn = tk.Button(root, text="Calculate", command=run)
calculate_btn.grid(column=0, row=2)

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't work. I have to first retrieve file locations first, then do calculations. I still get the same NameError that 'booked_file_path' is not defined but this time it's saying it in my `NoShowGUI.py` file

Comment: Well, this can other problem - you create `local` variable `booked_file_path` in function `open_file` and it doesn't exists in other functions (like `run` . You should add line `global booked_file_path` inside `open_file` to inform this function that you want assign value to external/global variable `booked_file_path` - and then `run` should have access to global `booked_file_path`

Comment: I added minimal working code which uses `import` to run code from other file